# Nodejs request post multiple sets of data?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I have a lot of requests to make in a row all to the same URL but each time I have to pass a different parameter. I was wondering if there was any way to make theses in one call? This is the current data in the request options object

```
form: {
    encrValue: encrValue
}
```

Or a way of knowing when they are all complete which is a bigger issue then the multiple requests part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use what the API accepts, and if it doesn't accept multiple requests then you can't do it.
A good way to send them all together is to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

For example:

```
const arrOfPromises = [];
for(const item of items) {
    arrOfPromises.push(fetch('getSomethingForThisItem', { body: JSON.stringify(item) }));
}

Promise.all(arrOfPromises)
.then(res => console.log('this is the array of responses:', res))
.catch(err => console.error('Oops, something went wrong!', err));
```